# Formally, what is the plus/minus $\pm$ object?

Tags: functions, notation

My guess is this:

$$
\pm: F \to F\times F
$$

where $F$ is a field.

For instance, $\pm 2$ maps $2 \in \mathbb{R}$  to the tuple $(2,-2) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.

Is it correct to think of the $\pm$ in this manner?

Comment: You can think about it like that, I guess? But in most cases, that's pretty useless, since $\pm$ is mostly used in referencing multiple roots of a polynomial, or something of the sort.

Comment: I don't think the formalism is quite consistent with mathematical practice; for instance, in the quadratic formula, one writes something like
$$
\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a},
$$
which only makes sense in your notation if you also view $-b$ as  meaning the vector $(-b, -b)$.

Comment: I would expect that applying $\pm$ twice to $2$ returns $2$, but this definition returns $\pm (2,-2)$, and it's not clear how to interpret that. Obviously interpreting it as $(\pm 2, \pm -2)=((2,-2),(-2,2))$ just creates a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a formalism, it's better to replace the $\pm$ symbol with something else altogether, because it's hard to make sense of expressions like $1 \pm \sqrt5$ if you regard $\pm$ as an operator.

For example, instead of writing $1 \pm \sqrt5$ you could write

$$1 + \varepsilon \sqrt5 \quad\mathrm{where}\quad \varepsilon \in \{-1,1\}.$$

This can be useful when dealing with formulas where at least one of the symbols $\pm$ or $\mp$ occurs multiple times. It lets the formula itself provide an answer to the questions, "If one of the $\pm$ signs is positive, must they all be positive? If one of the $\pm$ signs is negative, must they all be negative?"
If you use the same $\varepsilon$ throughout the formula, the answer to both questions is "yes";
if you define multiple factors like $\varepsilon_1 \in \{-1,1\}$ and $\varepsilon_2 \in \{-1,1\}$ then the answer to both questions is "no."

I have seen this technique used in formal proofs.

Answer (score 2):

Often it is used to code two different equations.  One with $+$ the other with $-$.  [That is easier than trying to imagine equations involving addition of numbers to pairs of numbers.]

For example,
$$
x_{\pm} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$
is a short way to write two equations:
$$
x_{+} = \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\qquad
x_{-} = \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking it's not correct. When we say the solution to the equation $x^2-1$ is $\pm 1$, that's not the same thing as $(1,-1)$, which cannot be a solution owing to the fact that it lives in the wrong space.

Closer might be $\{1,-1\}$, but that's still not really correct -- think of the $\pm$ that occurs in the quadratic formula, for instance. Best to think of $\pm$ as shorthand with no formal meaning.